# How can I create a Field Dependency between a Picklist and a Text field; Text field is dependent on the value selected in the Picklist?

Tags: picklist, custom-field, administration, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

How can I create a field dependency, where if the user selects the 'Other' option from the picklist field, a corresponding text field named 'Other' should dynamically appear for them to input additional information?

> Here's the **scenario**: I have a picklist field with five options,
> representing different types of documents that can be attached. The
> last option is 'Other'. When the user selects 'Other', a text field
> named 'Other' should appear below, allowing them to enter the name of
> the document they have attached.

Comment: Can you tried in Lightning record form with Dynamic action to achieve this? ref:https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_create_dynamic_action.htm&type=5

Comment: @Raj Thank you! I've tried and it is possible to create the dynamic form. I want to know if Is there any other way to create field dependency without it. kindly share your exposure and knowledge.

Comment: As per my knowledge, It's can be done via `Dynamic action` (without code) only. But if you like achieve this via LWC, i think it's can do. But you have tried first if you stuck create a new question for this. For this question, please drop that answer and accept it. So it's helpful for others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

@raj Thanks, Raj. I have achieved the expected result with `Lightning Dynamic Action` as per your Suggestion. I used the Component visibility and created the dependency

[image]